# i have two dictionary as stated below. i want to merge it into one nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key, key-value-store

a = {'thames': 'low', 'river cam': 'high', 'dickler': 'moderate', 'mil': 'severe', 'bourton': 'low'}
b = {'town1': ['thames, bourton'], 'town2': ['river cam'], 'town3': ['dickler','mil']}
c = {}
d = {}

#this is my code

```
c = {}

d = {}

for key in b.keys():
    c[key] = d
for k,v in a.items():
    if k in b.values():
        d[k] = v
```

desired output:
c = {'town1': {'thames':'low', 'bourton': 'low'}, 'town2': {'river cam': 'high'}, 'town3': {'dickler': 'moderate', 'mil': 'severe'}}

Comment: Your desired output is not valid Python syntax. Did you mean `{'town1': {'thames': 'low', 'bourton': 'low'}, 'town2': {'river cam': 'high'}, 'town3': {'dickler': 'moderate', 'mil': 'severe'}}`?

Comment: oh sorry, yeah i meant that. Thanks

Comment: Also, I suppose `['thames, bourton']` should be `['thames', 'bourton']`. Anyway, there is already a correct answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
for key,values in b.items():
    c[key] = {}
    for element in values:
        c[key][element] = a[element]
```